# Can a JWT be stateful?

Tags: authentication, jwt, stateful

I have always opt for having jwt over session because of the less over head in the backend side (keeping in mind that it all depends on the use case) but the major issue I am having with it is the invalidation of the token, for an example : in case of the user being deactivated, the relevant jwt would still be valid until it gets expired. Is there anyway to overcome this issue in a cost effective manner ?

PS - however I saw the term " revoking JWT " in the [cookbook section on the featherjs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/revoke-jwt.html)
framework. but its still looks like they are using redis as a lookup which in turns make it inherit drawback of using sessions.

Comment: JWT can be decoded at client side, make sure you don't put any secret info in it.

Comment: That I understand @ArjunVachhani but my question is how to make it stateful incase you need to invalidate the token before it gets expired

Comment: Don't store critical info in JWT like count of failed login attempts etc. You could probably store some info like user is has completed step 3 out of step 5 and probably some info which is not critical. And If you are storing JWT in cookie, then remove/update JWT from cookie on state change. if you are storing JWT in form field then remove it from form field.

Comment: Also validate that JWT is not modified by client, once you get it back from the client.

Answer (score 3):

Once a JWT is issued it is valid for as long as the `exp` claim value. You can't revoke a JWT, it's not how JWTs are meant to work.

As you pointed, out there are ways of mimicking the behaviour of revocation, but you need two things for that:

- you need to have a database with information about which tokens are revoked
- you have to make sure that whenever you consume the token you check online with the database.

There is no other way to do that.

If you really have a need to revoke JWTs it means that you need sessions, and you shouldn't be using JWTs for that. You can have a look at [this article](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/) to learn why. If you decide to stick to JWTs, have a look at this [best practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-best-practices/) article I wrote to know what to watch for.

Comment: The first article you mentioned looks like is against any kind of JWT, but in my understand is more against stateless authentication tokens. In my opinion stateful JWTs authentication tokens are possible and it helps to create a default token format for any application instead of relying of each frameworks obscure custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It can! My understand is that JWT is just a "standard" on how tokens can be defined and created. It doesn't "force" you to use it statefully or statelessly. This may looks weird because we only see developers and articles explaining how to use JWT statelessly, and unfortunately that's a limited approach on how JWTs can help us. If you carefully read [articles like this](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/) you can understand that they are more about being against stateless tokens in general rather than against stateful JWTs. It just happens that most people tend to implement JWTs as stateless tokens so it looks the only way to use it.

Stateful non-JWT tokens are implemented with no standard in different frameworks. NodeJS's Express, Java's Apache Tomcat, Java's Spring Boot, PHP's Laravel, Python's Django, each one has a different approach on stateful token formats and signature/encryption algorithms. The token's content can vary from framework to framework so there is no standard, and that's where JWT standarization help us.

When you start defining your stateful JWT claims you may find some of the "default" ones to be useless, and there is nothing wrong with it. If you plan to store the stateful JWT inside a cookie, JWT's "exp" claim (token expiration date) is useless because you can set the expiration inside cookie's Expires attribute and well in the database, so you don't need to set it in the JWT at all. Your application will always check for database validation before blindly accepting a valid signed JWT. You can find the "sub" field is not enough for you, and you need other fields such as "deviceId" and "userId". You are free to create as many claims as you want the way you want, using a JSON readable format with a default signature algorithm, that's what it's all about.

Stateful tokens generation implementations on the frameworks I mentioned before are often signed by symmetric HMAC. When using JWT you can easily change between symmetric (HMAC) and assymetric (RSA). That's a plus you get when using JWT for that.

It's a shame not many people discuss about this, stateful JWTs are possible and I personally think is a very nice way to use them.

Comment: I disagree with your approach. JWTs are stateless tokens. When you say that you have a "stateful JWT" what you mean is "I'm using stateful tokens, but instead of putting a session ID in the cookie I use a JWT as the session ID". In fact, what is the point of going through all the hassle of creating and signing a JWT if you still need to call the DB to verify it? In such a case, you can just keep all the data in the DB and issue an opaque string as the token. I think there is no point in mixing these approaches.

Comment: What do you mean by an opaque string? If you want that token to be secure you must sign it somehow and JWT provides a default for it. A random string is not as secure as a signed payload.

Comment: If you keep the payload in the database (a stateful token), then the token itself does not need to be signed. It can be a random string. It needs to have enough entropy so that it's not easy to guess or brute-force it, but it does not need to be signed. JWTs need to be signed because they are stateless. The signature allows you to verify the authenticity of the JWT without the need to refer to a central database.

Comment: How much is "enough entropy"?
I believe the JWT's default implementation helps the developer to focus on some possibilites that are more secure than some frameworks tend to use.
And what if the whole JWT is not stored in the DB, but only some parts of its claims, such as "sub" and "iat"? In other words a JSON can be used as the token, not a random string with no meaning.

Comment: Use more than 25 characters and your string will be secure enough. Also, remember that JWT is not secure "by default". You can easily misconfigure JWTs and render them completely insecure. And again - if you keep some data in the DB, what is the point of splitting them among the JWT and the DB? There are no real pros of using a JWT as an identifier for a DB entry.

Comment: I disagree with your disagreement. You are hard to convince, looks like I need you to provide with some hands on example to explain more how it works in a real world scenario. I may do that later as it is complex and requires some context. But anyways thank you for your questions and persisting on this discussion.